# How to append a file's creation date to its filename?

Tags: python

I would like to create a python script that
appends the file created date to the end of the filename while retaining the oringinal file name (`Report`) for a batch of pdf documents.

```
directory = T:\WISAARD_Web Portal Projects\PortalLogging\WebLogExpert
filenames = Report.pdf
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you encounter while doing it?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os,time
root="/home"
path=os.path.join(root,"dir1")
os.chdir(path)
for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".pdf"):
        f,ext = os.path.splitext(files)        
        d=time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(files)).split() #here is just example. you can use strftime, strptime etc to format your date as desired
        filedate = d[-1]+"-"+d[-2]+"-"+d[-3]
        newname = f+filedate+ext
        try: 
            os.rename(files,newname)
        except Exception,e:
            print e
        else:
            print "ok: renamed %s to %s " %(files,newname)
```